# Odoo10 run ssh server

Tags: ssh, odoo-10

How can I run Odoo in ssh server on Ubuntu 16.04? I tried so much way but I could not make it run. I follow this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04#odoo-server-configuration) and it seems working but I can not access http://adress:8069 gives me an error. When I trying ./odoo-bin and it is working like that. But I dont know how can I make it always run in ssh server. 
Thank you.

Comment: What's the _exact_ error message? It's important to read those; they are usually designed to be helpful in finding and solving the problem.

Comment: It is browser error, can't establish a connection to the server.

Comment: Look in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$sudo -u odoo ./odoo-bin
```

`Odoo` must run with `odoo` user.